# I want modify dialog height and maintain the background

Tags: css, angular, dialog

I would like to adjust the height of an existing dialog, but keep scrollabble and background color, currently if I give it height then the background color will only expand at the specified height if scrolling down then the height will be lost.

[image]

Here is the code of dialogs height:

```
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dialog-layout-modal-body {
    max-height: 662px;
  }
}
```

If I give it a background color then it fills in at full screen width, I wouldn't want that.

What is the solution to keep the background color down, but I can adjust the height of the dialog?

Comment: can you elaborate with minimal HTML code as well...

if height is not calculating
give "overflow:hidden" or "float:left;width:100%" for the modal body

Comment: This dialog is created in another component and I just want to modify in that particular component. @manoj

Comment: I want the dialog to be of a certain height but scrollable.

Comment: try with overflow:auto

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you very much @manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dialog-layout-modal-body { overflow-y: auto;}
}
```

Hope this will help.